# Paypal: linking existing Sandbox Account with developer account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I dont have access anymore to the sandbox.paypal.com

In [Developer Account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) I tried:

```
Want to link existing Sandbox Account with your developer account? *Click here* and provide credentials of your sandbox account.
```

After few redirections it refuses to sign me in:

```
Error

Relying Party Validation error: client_ID or redirect_uri provided in the request does not match any of the registered clients. Please check the request.
```

I've tried with two differents accounts, one of them do not have a live account, and it give me each time the same error without further explanation.

@paypaldev [filed a ticket on the issue](https://twitter.com/paypaldev/status/718503013258784769) but I'm not sure what to expect.

Do am I the only one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update here for everyone else as I followed up with François via Twitter. The internal teams were able to track down the issue that was causing the relaying party validation error, and it should now be fixed without needing a workaround. If anyone is still seeing an error, please let me know and I'll circle back with the teams working on the fix.

Comment: For now, everything works fine, thank you Jonathan, keep up the good work!